# C# time subtraction Issue

Tags: c#, datetime

I have been facing issue on time subtraction in C#.

For example I start timer on **4/5/2017 11:56:27 PM**  and end the timer in **5/5/2017 12:10:27 AM** when I subtract this it shows me result **23 hours**.

I want that it show exact time like 14 minutes. I am sharing my code as well.

```
double rate1 = Convert.ToDouble(rate.Text);
double value = rate1 / 3600;
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(text3.Text);
DateTime edt = DateTime.Parse(text5.Text);
var res = dt.Subtract(edt).ToString().Replace('-', ' ');
DateTime tt = Convert.ToDateTime(res);
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(text4.Text);
DateTime edt1 = DateTime.Parse(text6.Text);
var res1 = dt.Subtract(edt1).ToString().Replace('-', ' ');
double sec = TimeSpan.Parse(res).TotalSeconds;
double sec1 = TimeSpan.Parse(res1).TotalSeconds;
text7.Text = res.ToString();
text8.Text = res1.ToString();
```

Comment: It is backwards, you subtract the end time from the start time.  And then ignored the bug by adding code to get rid of the minus sign.  Start doing this correctly to get somewhere.

Comment: What is the exact output you want? This is not clear at all

Comment: Check your date format. It is `MM/DD/YYYY`. Your dates are in different months so the answer you are getting is correct.

Comment: Jus to be clear. Are the formats MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS ?

Comment: What locale are you in? en-US?

Comment: Your code would be MUCH easier to debug if the variables had meaningful names and if we knew what the values of things like `text3.Text` were. Ex. `DateTime startDateTime=DateTime.Parse("4/5/2017 11:56:27 PM")`.  It would also make it easier if you left out things like `rate1` and `value` which have no bearing on the operation in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're showing a lot of code that's difficult to reproduce for us, and the variable names are not the clearest. I'm assuming `dt` stands for "datetime", and `edt` stands for "end datetime". If that's correct, then you're subtracting the end date from the start date instead of the other way around (you should subtract the smaller from the larger).

So, here's how to get the difference between start and end (I'm using Hindi culture info for this):

```
    var dateFormatCulture = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
    var startDate = DateTime.Parse("4/5/2017 11:56:27 PM", dateFormatCulture);
    var endDate = DateTime.Parse("5/5/2017 12:10:27 AM", dateFormatCulture);
    var difference = endDate.Subtract(startDate);
```

You say you want "the exact time like 14 minutes". I'm not sure if that means you don't want to show the rest of the values, but here are a few ways you can display it.

```
Console.WriteLine($"General short string format: {difference:g}");

Console.WriteLine(
    "Custom string format: {0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes, {3} seconds",
    difference.Days, difference.Hours, difference.Minutes, difference.Seconds);

Console.WriteLine("In terms of minutes, the total minutes difference is: {0}", 
    difference.TotalMinutes);
```

Notice that there's a difference between the second an third example in the methods being called to show the minutes . `Minutes` will display just the minutes portion of the difference. `TotalMinutes` will display the entire difference in terms of minutes. In your case they are the same, but if the difference was 1 hour and 14 minutes, `Minutes` would still be `14`, but `TotalMinutes` would be `74`.

The output looks like:

[image]

Comment: I think part of the problem is that we're using en-US locale and he might be using something different so it's unclear what he's looking for

Comment: Thanks @JoePhillips. Updated with Hindi culture info, which is `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: This looks much better and matches what he's asking now :)

Comment: Thanks Sir Yes this is what exactly i want. 14 minutes means the actual difference between two times

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a copy/paste error. In this line, did you mean to reference `dt1` rather than `dt`?

```
var res1 = dt.Subtract(edt1).ToString().Replace('-', ' ');
```